# Is there any way to compare a value at certain index with all the values to its right till it doesn't match?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Lets say I have an array :

```
$ar = array(0,1,0,0,0,1,0)
```

I want to compare the value at `$ar[2]`, i.e. `0` with all the values to its right until stops matching.
By this. I meant that, `$ar[2] == $ar[3], $ar[2] == $ar[4]`, and so on until it finds a mismatch, lets say at `$ar[12]`, i.e. `$ar[2] != $ar[12]`.
So this would tell me that `$ar[2]` is equal to all values to its right until `$ar[12]`.

Now, how would I do that in the code. The array can be of any size.

My code was this :

```
class JumpingClouds {
    public function jump() {
        $ar = array(0,1,0,0,0,1,0);
        for ($i=0; $i < count($ar) ; $i++) { 
            if ($ar[$i] == $ar[$i++]) {
                if($ar[$i++] == $ar[$i+2]) {
                    # code...
                }
            } else {
                # code...
            }
        }
    }
}

$j = new JumpingClouds();
$j->jump();
```

But couldn't do it for a dynamic array since I want the array to be a user input in future with any size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a `while` loop to loop over the elements after the one your looking at and compare it with the match value.  The `while` also checks for the end of the array.

I've passed the array into the constructor of the class, so that the `upTo()` method can be called with as many values as you want on the same array (without passing it in each time).

This will return `false` if the from part is larger than the array...

```
$ar = array(0,1,0,0,0,1,0);
$from=2;

$scanner = new Scan($ar);

var_dump($scanner->upTo($from));

class Scan {
    private $values;

    public function __construct( array $values )    {
        $this->values = $values;
    }

    public function upTo( int $from )    {
        // Get number of elements in the array
        $size = count($this->values) - 1;
        // If start is past end of array, return false
        if ( $from > $size )    {
            return false;
        }
        // Store value to check against
        $match = $this->values[$from];
        // Loop, checking if the element looking at is the same and not the end of the array
        while ( $this->values[$from] == $match && $from < $size)  {
            // Move onto next element
            $from++;
        }
        // Return the position of the last element that matches
        return $from;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you please explain your solution. I am not able to understand.

Comment: I've added comments to the code to see if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `for` loop. You can use below function. It return `index` when the match is found otherwise returns -1

```
$ar = array(0,1,0,0,0,1,0); 
$from = 2; //Need to match from 2 index onwards

echo $index = jump( $ar, $from );     
//if -1 no match

function jump($ar, $from) {

    $count = count ( $ar );

    if( $from >= $count ) {
        return -1;
    }
    $compareValue = $ar[$from];
    for( $i = 0; $i < count( $ar); $i++ ) {
        if( $i <= $from ) {
            continue; //Index is below so continue
        }

        if( $ar[$i] != $compareValue ) {
           return $i + 1;   
        }   
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. I was tweaking it a little bit for my needs. But couldn't do it. What if there are 3 continuous zeros? for this can it move directly by double step? like `$ar[2]+2` ? I have to find the shortest path to reach from one end to other.

Comment: You have to loop through array 1 step at a time. Skipping a step would lead to unexpected results unless you know the structure of the array.

Comment: Okay. I'll still try it. Thank you so much.